# How to update a spinner dynamically?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I've been trying to update my spinner in android dynamically but nothing I try has been working.

This is the following code I'm using to update the spinner.

```
typeList = dbAdapter.getList(); //array list with the values

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
groupSpinner.postInvalidate();
groupSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The values of typeList are correct but they're not being updated in the Spinner.

Comment: I fixed this by just created a whole new adapter... I feel like I shouldn't have had to do that though.

Comment: Do u have one instance of adapter. if you initialize your adapter again notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work.

Answer (score 31):

Actually, you either have to call clear/add on the adapter, or create and set a new adapter.  The adapter does not retain a reference to your list (it is only calling toArray on your list at construction), so there is no way for it to update itself.

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newStringList);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 31):

You can't directly modify the original `List` then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` like on other adapters, as it doesn't hold on to the original `List`.

You can, however, achieve the same result using the adapter itself, like so:

```
spinnerAdapter.clear();
spinnerAdapter.addAll(updatedListData);
spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // optional, as the dataset change should trigger this by default
```

*Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38738734/1508887) answer from user392117.*

**edit:** By default, methods that change the list like `add()` and `remove()` automatically call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (see [Android Developer Documentation for  setNotifyOnChange(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange(boolean)) )

> public void setNotifyOnChange (boolean notifyOnChange)
>
> Control whether methods that change the list (add, addAll(java.util.Collection), addAll(java.lang.Object[]), insert, remove, clear, sort(java.util.Comparator)) automatically call notifyDataSetChanged. **If set to false, caller must manually call notifyDataSetChanged() to have the changes reflected in the attached view. The default is true, and calling notifyDataSetChanged() resets the flag to true.**

So you should not need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time. If you find that this is the case, you can use setNotifyOnChange(true)

```
spinnerAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true); //only need to call this once
spinnerAdapter.add(Object); //no need to call notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Works without notifyDataSetChanged() for replacing the entire list. Haven't tried just adding to the existing list. I guess in that case you might have to call it.

Comment: Note: if you are extending `BaseAdapter` you will need to add these methods to your adapter implementation.

Answer (score 13):

You only need to call setAdapter() once and you call [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) to update the data.

Comment: do I need to create a whole new adapter because that isn't working? When I click the spinner, the values in the list are not updated.

Comment: I have found `NotifyDataSetChanger()` to work in Lists, but I have not seen it work in Spinners. I guess there is some internal difference that requires you to create a new adapter each time.

Answer (score 11):

> When you have data changed in your list and when you want to update
>   the spinner then
>
> Create a new object of the adapter and set that adapter to the
>   spinner. It will work sure.
>
> Best of luck.

Edit: Also you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a typo or something? Which is the difference between `dbAdapter` and `adapter`. If the Spinner has already the adapter, you don't have to re-assign it. More over, the only think you have to do is update the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

```
typeList = adapter.getList(); //array list with the values
// change the values, and then
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: dbAdapter is my link to the database adapter is a custom adapter i made that extends BaseAdapter and implements SpinnerAdapter. I tried what you suggested and that did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Using add/remove on your adapter and using notifyDataSetChanged() enables you not having to create new adapters over and over again.

Declare your adapter global

```
ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter;
```

When you add something to the List of Objects the adapter is attached to (Strings or whatever object you use) add an add function to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged:

```
adaper.add(Object);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and when you remove an item from the List add also:

```
adapter.remove(Object);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**edit:** By default, methods that change the list like add() and remove() automatically call notifyDataSetChanged() (see [Android Developer Documentation for  setNotifyOnChange(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange(boolean)) )

> public void setNotifyOnChange (boolean notifyOnChange)
>
> Control whether methods that change the list (add, addAll(java.util.Collection), addAll(java.lang.Object[]), insert, remove, clear, sort(java.util.Comparator)) automatically call notifyDataSetChanged. **If set to false, caller must manually call notifyDataSetChanged() to have the changes reflected in the attached view. The default is true, and calling notifyDataSetChanged() resets the flag to true.**

So you should not need to call notifyDataSetChanged() every time. If you find that this is the case you you can use setNotifyOnChange(true)

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true); //only need to call this once
adapter.add(Object); //no need to call notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the underlying data and call the notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.

```
   list.clear();
  list.add("A");
      list.add("B");
  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

After you change your data, you will need to add the following code:

```
typeList = dbAdapter.getList()              
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,typeList);            
groupSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently after you do `typeList = dbAdapter.getList()`, the variable `typeList` points to a different List rather than the one you fed to the adapter originally and the adapter would be somewhat confused.

So you should use the following code:

```
typeList.clear();
typeList.addAll(dbAdapter.getList());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set up the spinner adapter add

```
spinnerAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

From then on when you add new data it will be automatically updated.

Comment: For ArrayAdapter, the default is already true. For use with Spinners, doing this has no effect - as mentioned in comments on previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to initialize the adapter with `ArrayList<T>`. Otherwise, you might get an exception.

```
val list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
private lateinit var spinnerAdapter:  ArrayAdapter<String>
```

After that initialize the adapter:

```
spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        list) // initialize with empty arrayList
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    binding.spinnerCurrency.apply {
        adapter = spinnerAdapter
}
```

After that when you have data clear and add all list.

```
 spinnerAdapter.clear()
 spinnerAdapter.addAll(list)
```