# Android / Changing the text in specific spinner item

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am designing a mobile app for jewellery shop. In Android, for the jewellery product description page, I have a Spinner with some ring sizes with their text `5` to `25` set by using a custom array list adapter.

I have a Radio Group of `18 carat` or `22 carat` that work along with the Spinner, and if different Radio Button for carat is selected, then the spinner text should change along with it only for a few ring sizes, for example `17 - Ships in 24 hours` if the ring size is ready to ship and `18` if the ring size is to be newly made based upon customer's order.

To achieve this, if a different size Radio Button is selected, I create a new array list, add all the new text again for spinner and then use array adapter again.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Description.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sizes);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In doing so, the Spinner automatically defaults to the first item `5` always, even if previously the spinner item selected was, for example, `17` size for a different carat Radio Button.

And also, the other details corresponding to other Text Views in the same activity, for example price, discount, making charge, gold weight, delivery date, whether product is ready to ship, etc. automatically default to the ring size `5`.

So, is it possible to change the text of a specific Spinner item programmatically if a different carat Radio Button is selected? Is it possible to achieve that without creating a new array list, add all the new text to it and making use of array adapter again? And if so how?

Comment: have you checked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283337/how-to-update-a-spinner-dynamically

Comment: I guess you're applying adapter on radio button change on spinner. If your ring sizes are same for both 18 and 22 carat then you do not need to set the adapter again.

Comment: @peco: If Array Adapter is used, then with `setAdapter` function call, the spinner item gets defaulted automatically to the first element in the spinner list. Is there any way to avoid this and making use of `setSelection` function call for setting the previously selected spinner item again?

Comment: @Abhishek: Then how will you handle the changing of text to the specific spinner item only, changing the selected spinner element from `17` to `17 - Ships in 24 hours` without setting the array adapter again?

Comment: So basically your one array contain only number like 17 and other 17 - Ships in 24 hours am I right ?

Comment: @Abhishek: Actually that my array list for 18 carat contains some set of ring sizes ready to be shipped in 24 hours and that my array list for 22 carat contains different set of ring sizes ready to be shipped in 24 hours. Is it possible to change the text of the different spinner items if chosen different caratage without making use of the `setAdapter` function call again?

Comment: If do not want to use setAdapter and two different array at all. Still you can achieve this but you need to add condition on onItemSelectedListener of spinner. That'll not be a good method tho.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198699/discussion-between-v-raman-and-abhishek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sizes` is an ArrayList, to change a particular item in the spinner try using

```
sizes.set(index,newItem)
```

If you want to change the 3rd item to 10,

```
sizes.set(2,10) //I am assuming the sizes arraylist is integer arraylist. if not change to required data type
```

then execute

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // This will refresh you spinner.
```

instead of re-setting the adapter on the spinner. And then if you want, execute

```
s1.setSelection(2)
```

The `s1.setAdapter(adapter);` should only be executed once(when the spinner is initialised).

```
public void refreshSpinner(int index,int newValue){ 
    sizes.set(index,newValue);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //Only if you want to select the new value
    s1.setSelection(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

Select the Spinner element at index position 2
(It will select third element/item from Spinner)

```
s1.setSelection(2);
```

Comment: Yes, I do agree that this is indeed possible and this is what I tried out to do, and this will process all the code in `s1.onItemSelectedListener`. But is there any way to change the text of specific spinner item without using an adapter and without the spinner item to automatically roll back to the first element by default and setting it back again to the previously selected spinner item programmatically?