# Spinner doesn't show array and texts

Tags: java, android, spinner

The spinner doesn't work.
It didn't use to show arrow when I was just playing with it in design mode, it's not showing text after I implemented it with some code somehow.

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

```
Spinner spinner;
ArrayList spinnerArrayList;
ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinnerArrayList = new ArrayList();
    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerArrayList);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    spinnerArrayList.add("Guitar");
    spinnerArrayList.add("Drums");
    spinnerArrayList.add("Keyboard");

}
```

Comment: You're updating the `ArrayList` after assigning it to the adapter. By default, `Spinner` doesn't keep a reference to the original list added to the adapter so to retain the changes you should use what has been provided here in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45192458/8244632) link.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is you are changing your ArrayList after setting up the adapter.
So adapter doesn't know that the data is changed.

You can solve this in 2 ways :

1. Add elements in the ArrayList before setting up the adapter
2. Use  notifyDataSetChanged() at the end of the code or whenever you change the ArrayList

Like this :  `spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create `ArrayAdapter` to populate your spinner if the list you want to insert is static.
I recommend using a way easier and direct method to avoid this hassle.

In  **strings.xml**:

```
<string-array name="list_spinner">
<item>Guitar</item>
<item>Drums</item>
<item>Keyboard</item>
</string-array>
```

In the layout that contains your spinner:

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/list_spinner"
    />
```

And You're Done!

**EXTRA:**
If you want to make your spinner responsive to item selection in your spinner, add this code to the corresponding .java file of the layout containing the spinner in the `onCreate()` method:

```
final Spinner spin=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String item_name=spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Log.e("Selected item : ",item_name);
}

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    });
```